# How can I create a variable instance of type int in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, static

After executing the following code, no matter which button I press, it will always print 4. I suppose that's because the variable `i` is a pointer rather than an instance. Any quick fixes?

```py
    import tkinter as tk


        def print_num(num):
            print(num)


        root = tk.Tk()
        for i in range(5):
            tk.Button(root, text=str(i), command=lambda: print_num(i)).pack()

        root.mainloop()
```

I expect that when I press the button, it prints the number assigned to that button, but I'm always getting 4

Comment: `command=lambda i=i: print_num(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You need put an parameter on lambda, for example `a` and put this parameter on your function and make it equal to `i` on your for loop.

```
import tkinter as tk


def print_num(num):
    print(num)

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(5):
    tk.Button(root, text=str(i), command=lambda a=i: print_num(a)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```